# Is accessing static variables inside a non-static function considered bad coding?

Tags: php

Here is an example that I am working on, and didn't know if it was considered bad coding?

```
class CounterClass
{
    private $counter = 0;
    static $counterOverall = 0;

   function CountUp()
   {
      $this->$counter++;
      self::$counterOverall++;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

There is nothing inherently "bad" about accessing static variables from non-static methods. By itself, it's a perfectly acceptable practice.

Like most things in software engineering, it's just a tool, which can sometimes be perfect for a job at hand, while being a poor choice in other cases. It's up to the programmer to decide when best to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any good reason to categorize this code under the "bad" category.
Using `static` is giving you a shared memory across all instances of your class, which is just what you need in this case. I hope this helps!